# Android GridView and threading wait

Tags: android, multithreading, android-listview, android-adapter, android-gridview

I have a method `playSoE()` that performs an operation on each view and updates the ArrayAdapter and thus GridView after each operation. I want to do is have the code wait for 1 second after the update is done, and then perform the operation on the next view. For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    public void playSoE(){
        for(int i = 0; i < primesLE; i++) //iterates to each view
            mAdapter.setPositionColor(index, 0xffff0000 + 0x100 * index); //operation performed on view
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //updates adapter/GridView

            //Code that waits for one second here

        }
}
```

I have tried many threading APIs but none of them seem to work, they've either froze up the application for `primesLE` seconds and shown all the operations at the end, skip the second wait and just performed all the operations at once, or gotten an Exception related to concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the update itself is quick, you should not be creating additional threads at all.  Create a `Handler` and use `postDelayed(...)` to time your updates in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to take a look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Put the wait code at the `doInBackground()` and then the following that affects the visual on the `onPostExecute()`

All you do on `doInBackground()` will not freeze your application.

Comment: What do you suggest the wait code to be? I'm trying the same APIs I used before and they're still causing the same behavior.